# Get actual URL from TinyURL

Tags: objective-c, web-services, web-applications, ios4, redirect

I want the user to get the actual URL from the TinyURL or Tiny.cc services, or any other URL redirectors. So is it possible for me to get the actual long URLs from the short redirected URLs, without making a browswer application that runs in the background?

Thanks in advance.

**Header:**

```
#import "UntitledViewController.h"


@implementation UntitledViewController

- (id)init 
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tinyurl.com/a3cx"];
        [self loadTinyURL:url];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadTinyURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                                  delegate:self];
    if (!connection) 
        NSLog(@"could not connect with: %@", url);
}

- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
             willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
            redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    int statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

    // http statuscodes between 300 & 400 is a redirect ...
    if (response && statusCode >= 300 && statusCode < 400) 
        NSLog(@"redirecting to : %@", [request URL]);

    return request;
}

@end
```

**Implementation:**

```
//
//  UntitledViewController.h
//  Untitled
//
//  Created by tushar chutani on 11-04-19.
//  Copyright 2011 Fleetwood park secondary . All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UntitledViewController : UIViewController {

}

- (void)loadTinyURL:(NSURL *)url;

@end
```

Comment: There is really no point in checking the status to see if it is a redirect because the method should only be called when it is a redirect and it has a redirectResponse. That said my example checks and makes sure that tinyurl.com is actually doing the redirect, if you remove that check and just check redirectResponse is not nil it will then log all redirects even after tinyurl does the redirect.

Comment: That's definitely true, I do much the same for Twitter / Facebook integration in an app I work on. Inside the check on response and statusCode I check the response URL object to figure out the sender (using the -rangeOfString: method), then I inform the caller through a delegate that the redirect URL is found. But my goal was to give the basics, further customization is exercise for the reader :)

Comment: I am trying to do the same with IOS5. Does anyone have an example of code to catch the redirected URL, from the first tinyURL?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following code:

```
#import "TinyURLHandler.h"


@interface TinyURLHandler (Private)
- (void)loadTinyURL:(NSURL *)url;
@end


@implementation TinyURLHandler

- (id)init 
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self) 
   {
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tinyurl.com/a3cx"];
      [self loadTinyURL:url];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)loadTinyURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                                 delegate:self];
   if (!connection) 
      NSLog(@"could not connect with: %@", url);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
   NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
   int statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
   NSLog(@"%d : %@", statusCode, [NSHTTPURLResponse 
                                  localizedStringForStatusCode:statusCode]);   
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   [connection release];
   NSLog(@"finished");
}

- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
             willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
            redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
   NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
   int statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

   // http statuscodes between 300 & 400 is a redirect ...
   if (response && statusCode >= 300 && statusCode < 400) 
      NSLog(@"redirecting to : %@", [request URL]); 

   return request;
}

@end
```

**@ openingsposter**: I'm not 100% sure why you want to see the original project, I guess it's because you want to figure out what would be a good way to extract the final URL? Well, what I would suggest is you create a delegate and inform the caller once you got the final URL. If you need an example, I can add more source code ...

Comment: can you upload your project some where so I can have a look at the entire project? Please

Comment: You can download the example iOS project from my Dropbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6487838/TinyURL.zip

Comment: Depends, if the redirection happens through the HTTP standard, which means the HTTP header returned by the webserver must contain a HTTP status code for redirection. Perhaps you could show me the URL you use to retrieve the MP3?

Comment: That link shows a HTTP status code 404, i.e. the file does not exist. There is no redirection for that file. I tried another file and it does redirect for me, is it working for you as well? http://mp3bear.com/inc/audio.php?id=2520

Comment: To figure out the HTTP status codes, I recommend you install FireFox and use the build-in _Web Console_ (_Tools_ menu).

Comment: This file also shows a proper 302 for me: http://mp3bear.com/inc/audio.php?id=883041

Comment: I've updated the code a bit, added 2 delegate methods. You'll notice you get a 404 on the method called __-connection:didReceiveResponse:__. I'm not sure what the _mp3bear_ server does, but it's not a normal redirect that's happening. Perhaps their is some hidden HTML page that has some JavaScript to do the redirection, perhaps they're doing something different.

Comment: I'm beginning to think they're using cookies or something to decide where someone gets a status 302 or a status 404. It seems if i visit the page with the link, then the redirect works fine. If I haven't visited the page with the link, the redirect fails. You might have to visit the page **http://mp3bear.com/waka-flocka-flame-no-hands-feat-roscoe-dash-wale** before following the redirect URL:  **http://mp3bear.com/inc/audio.php?id=1233**

Answer (score 3):

The NSURLConnection has a call back [connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html). At this point you can inspect the redirectResponse to see where you are going.

**UPDATE:**

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
             willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
            redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
{
    //Make sure tinyurl is doing the redirection
    if([[[redirectResponse URL] host] compare:@"tinyurl.com" 
                                      options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        NSLog(@"Redirect Location: %@", [request URL]);
    }

    //call [connection cancel]; to cancel the redirect and stop receiving data
    //return nil; to cancel redirect but continue receiving data
    //return request; will continue the redirection as normal

    return request;
}
```

Comment: is it possible for you to give me some kind of example for this?

Comment: @user710704: it is quite straight forward, implement the method in your delegate and the new URL will be in the request's `URL` property.

Comment: @user710704, edit your question and post the code you have written so far.